# Images are not aligning properly in the horizontal RecyclerView in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

[image]

and
[image]

As you can see, the images don't seem to be aligning with each other very well. It seems to happen when the text for "Hobby" grows longer than the ones next to it. I still can't seem to fix this though. Here's the xml for the horizontal view:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"

        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

and here's the xml for my adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    >
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dog_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="194dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dog_img"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hobby"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I really want the images to line up with each other regardless of the length of the "Hobby". Sorry if this might seem a bit basic, but I'm new to Android Studio. Anyways, thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` from ImageView and  Add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you set the scale type to centre inside and another tag adjustViewBounds like the following code.

**android:adjustViewBounds="true" and android:scaleType="centerInside"**

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dog_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"


            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            
            />
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: I'll recommend you one more thing, to add maxHeight in imageView field, so that your images cannot exceed that particular height size. I hope it will solve your problem.